# Can we Login without using identity in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I am a beginner to ASP.NET.I just started learning it.The tutorials I'm watching shows that it requires to use identity to login into ASP.NET.I want to know is their any way to login without using identity if yes then how because i couldn't found any proper answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. One way is to use Cookie Authentification  (More informations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

It's a simple alternative, quick to use and the main idea is that the login informations are stored as claims in a cookie that gets sent back and forward between the browser and the server.

Comment: Does that only apply to Core?